# Unable to detect the System Admin in a validation rule error condition formula

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I have a business scenario where I would like to restrict the transition to the `Accepted` status of the Quote object, only to the admin.

For this I configured a validation rule with the following error condition formula:

```
AND( 
   NOT($Profile.Name == 'System Administrator'), 
   ISCHANGED(Status), 
   TEXT(Status) = "Accepted" 
)
```

The problem is that this rule is preventing all types of users(admin and non-admin ones) from transitioning to the `Accepted` status.

In a bunch of other threads I have checked that this is actually considered an accurate approach.

***Notes***

I know that out there exist other approaches that are considered more efficient and consistent, like i.e. using a permission set, and referring to it, and not hardcoding the profile name in the rule, or even using custom settings.

In this case I am interested why Salesforce can detect this simple token through the `$Profile.Name` field.

Comment: Seems a duplicate to this question: [Excluding System admin from this validation rule](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70778/excluding-system-admin-from-this-validation-rule)

Comment: Well, I think it's not really a duplicate as even if I replace the aforementioned rule in: IF (
    $Profile.Name = "System Administrator" , FALSE,
    AND( 
        ISCHANGED(Status), 
        TEXT(Status) = "Accepted"
    )
)
I am still unable to set the status to "Accepted". You can try it out in case.

Comment: Have you checked which one is failing? `NOT($Profile.Name == 'System Administrator')` or `TEXT(Status) = "Accepted"`?

Comment: The `NOT($Profile.Name == 'System Administrator')` condition.

Comment: Try `$Profile.Name != 'System Administrator'`

Comment: Not working with that approach either. Wonder how one would presume that `NOT($Profile.Name == 'System Administrator')` and `$Profile.Name != 'System Administrator'` give different outcomes.

Comment: can you please debug the value of `$Profile.Name`?

Comment: I really don't see any issues in your Validation Rule. I in fact was able to write the same one and could see it working. You may like to verify if this validation rule is active or not.

Comment: Thanks @PragatiJain for the hint. After debugging the validation rule, I saw that the value read for the profile was `Systemadministrator`. Very weird because when I query all the profiles in an anonymous context, I see that the name of the admin profile is `System Administrator` indeed. Is there any hidden field like a `DeveloperName` field or something that holds this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to translation because profile name translated to a language used on Org. We already have a post regarding that ([$profile.name in validation rule not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96189/profile-name-in-validation-rule-not-working)). You can choose one of the suggested solutions from this post.